# Find and Extract Text in DOM

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I am looking to extract a piece of text from the DOM. The data I am interested in is "`1234567`"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function example() {     
           launchChat("ABC", "1234567", "Sample Data", "Customer");      
 }
</script>
```

So far this is what I have got -

```
$("head").find("script").each(function(i) {
    var scr = $(this).html();   
    var regExp = /launchChat(([^)]+))/; //Outputs everything in between the brackets
    var matches = scr.match(regex);
    console.log("match " +matches);     
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: should the code work dynamically, so if you have at the same position "891011" would work the same?

Comment: Yes the code should be dynamic. The position is always the same.

Comment: You need to escape the literal parentheses, `\(` and `\)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok if it helps anyone at some point in the future, the answer is -

```
$("head").find("script").each(function(i) {
    var scr = $(this).html();
    if(scr.indexOf("launchChat") > 0){  
    var newTxt = scr.split('"');
    for (var i = 1; i < newTxt.length; i++) {
    console.log(newTxt[i].split('"')[3]);
    }   
}
});
```